# Stream Cart total price in flutter using firebase backend

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Please I'm stuck, I'm trying to stream product price from cart and sum up to get the total... here is my code...

```
   Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: firebaseFirestoreOperations.usersRef
                .doc(firebaseFirestoreOperations.getUserId())
                .collection('Cart')
                .doc('9oNFPyrUPN9wORFsyqvY')
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              var price = snapshot.data['price'];
              return CartBottomBar(
                totalPrice: price,
              );
            }),
      ),
```

Comment: what error you are having?

Comment: It prints cause I specified the document ID, need it to stream all the document in that collection, and select just the 'price' field

Answer (score 1):

```
 Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: firebaseFirestoreOperations.usersRef
                .doc(firebaseFirestoreOperations.getUserId())
                .collection('Cart')
                 .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {


              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {

              let total = 0;
//               snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {

               snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                  total += doc.data()['price'];
               });



                return Text('\$${total}  ');
             }
             
            return Text('Loading');
        
 
             
            }),
      ),
```

Check this ref: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes

Comment: It prints cause I specified the document ID, need it to stream all the document in that collection, and select just the 'price' field

Comment: remove .doc('9oNFPyrUPN9wORFsyqvY') then